# How to add a local script using wp_enqueue_script() on submit of a form?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress plugin , where on the plugin settings page , a user can add some inline script in a text-area  and click  on save

I want to get that script which user submits and enqueue in header/footer of the theme

I have tried this - but it adds the script when i click on submit on admin page but not on frontend

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // Enqueued script with localized data.
    wp_register_script( 'mapkitchenhandle', plugins_url( 'js/script.js', __FILE__ ) ); 

    wp_localize_script( 'mapkitchenhandle', 'trackcode', array('track' => $_POST['mapkitchentrackingcode']) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mapkitchenhandle');
}
```

can any one please help me out how to acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

On post you should save this data to the options table:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['mapkitchentrackingcode'])) {
    update_option('mapkitchentrackingcode', sanitize_text_field($_POST['mapkitchentrackingcode']));
}
```

I recommend you clean the `$_POST` variables before using them. I haven't bothered here.

Then hook up on `wp_enqueue_scripts` action and check if this `mapkitchentrackingcode` option is set and add it with `wp_localize_script()`:

```
function wp_1231_enqueue_scripts()
{
    wp_register_script('mapkitchenhandle', plugins_url('js/script.js', __FILE__)); 

    if (false !== $trackingCode = get_option('mapkitchentrackingcode')) {
        wp_localize_script('mapkitchenhandle', 'trackcode', array('track' => $trackingCode));    
    }

    wp_enqueue_script('mapkitchenhandle');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_1231_enqueue_scripts');
```